# In safari, Click event not emits while clicking on the image on which clip-path has set

Tags: safari, draggable, clip-path, mouseclick-event

I want to drag the image inside the div having the clip-path set. When I do inspect the element on that image element in Chrome and Firefox browsers, The image is selected in inspect element but when I do the same in Safari the parent element of the div having clip-path is selected not the Image.

**Note:** If I set the translateX and translateY value in transform to 0 which is set in the clip-path tag then it works but the clip-path moved from the place which I have set it by the calculation as per my need.

Here I have created a fiddle to test the issue. [http://jsfiddle.net/b4epxajz/]

I have also checked with the position relative and absolute but it didn't work.

I also moved the SVG to another location in the HTML page in my project but was not able to trace the image to drag.

I am using a jquery-ui draggable plugin to drag the image in my project.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.